# Crystal Report image from byte array not printing

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report with a class as a data source.  I have a byte array which I am passing a bitmap to but it isn't printing on the Crystal Report.  Please see my code below.

```
var d = new Label();
var eanCreator = new CreateEan();

var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    bf.Serialize(ms, eanCreator.createBitmap(1.5f, "1234567890"));
    var byteArray = ms.ToArray();

    var ld = new LabelData
    {
        PartNumber = "123",
        EanData = byteArray
    };
    d.SetDataSource(new List<LabelData> {ld});

    d.PrintOptions.PrinterName = @"\\SERVER\Printer";
    d.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
}
```

The print comes out, all data except the image is present.  I am using a class to create an EAN barcode, this part renders correctly to an image file, but just won't recognise it within Crystal Reports.

Comment: You likely need binary data, representing some kind of on-disk image format (bmp, jpg) - properly encoded and including header fields.

Comment: I have tried this method to create the byte array also `var byteArray = (byte[]) new ImageConverter().ConvertTo(eanCreator.createBitmap(1.5f, appData.EanNumber), typeof(byte[]));` but this results in a generic GDI error

Comment: You need to convert from internal bitmap to some image format (Crystal handles at least bmp and jpg), not to byte array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is similar to your code.  I use this method all the time to send an image to Crystal Reports without problems.

```
public static byte[] ConvertImageToByte(Image Value)
{
    if (Value != null)
    {
        MemoryStream fs = new MemoryStream();
        ((Bitmap)Value).Save(fs, ImageFormat.Jpeg);          
        byte[] retval= fs.ToArray(); 
        fs.Dispose();
        return retval;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem but the final output only black

Answer (score 0):

To be able to show the image on the report, when you pull the image Field of your DataSet, it has to be **IBlobFieldObject** in CR. I had a lot of trouble achieving this.
Eventually i removed the DataSet from the report (through 'Database expert') and re-added it. Also make sure, that your Image field is set to byte[] in the DataSet.