# Images on Crystal Report from DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

I'm really scratching my head on this one. I'm having trouble displaying images from a database on a Crystal Report. I have a working webpage that will added pictures to a SQL Server data table. The image field is set up as a Varbinary(max) and the server is SQL Server 2012.

The website will display pictures using this code;

```
            byte[] bytes = (byte[])GetData("SELECT Image FROM PRODUCTION.dbo.a_Traveler_Picture WHERE Id =" + id).Rows[0]["Image"];
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
```

The images in the database are both PNG and JPG bit maps.

I setup a sample Crystal Report that displays all the images and another text field. The report shows the text field but no images.

The Crystal Report version is 14.

Any suggestions on where to look here? I'd love to blame this on Crystal but I need it to work in Crystal, hahaha.

Comment: As i suggest use `ODBC connection` to display your images as well as the other data easily.

Comment: use my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976144/crystal-report-image-from-byte-array-not-printing/43993469#43993469 , I think it can solve your Problem,(P.S: My method convert Image to Byte array)